# How to filter all the rows in a dataframe_1 for each value in dataframe_2?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two spark dataframes: dataframe_1 with all the transactions of items and dataframe_2 with unique item ids. I want to filter all the rows from dataframe1 for each values in dataframe_2 .

I am trying to use a join query, but not sure how to proceed below is the main program written in scala:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val ss = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("Self_apriori_1").master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    import ss.implicits._

    val df_1 = ss.read.option("inferSchema", value=true).csv("/home/balakumar/scala work files/matrimony_3.csv")

     df_1.show()
     df_1.printSchema()

    val df_2 = ss.read.option("inferSchema" ,value=true) csv("/home/balakumar/scala work files/unique_1.txt")


   df_2.show(false)
   df_2.printSchema()
  }
}
```

Below are the dataframe_1 and dataframe_2 output for show() command 
for each values in dataframe_2, say (101), I require the following lines to be filtered where ever 101 is present

```
>|101|201| 301| 401|
>|101|201| 301|null|
>|101|201|null|null|
>|101|501|null|null|
```

Similarly for all the values in dataframe_2  I require all the rows to be filtered. Is it possible with join command?

```
>#dataframe_1

>+---+---+----+----+
> _c0|_c1| _c2| _c3
>+---+---+----+----+
>|101|201| 301| 401|
>|101|201| 301|null|
>|101|201|null|null|
>|101|501|null|null|
>|601|201| 301|null|
>|601|201|null|null|
>|601|501|null|null|
>+---+---+----+----+

>root
> |-- _c0: integer (nullable = true)
> |-- _c1: integer (nullable = true)
> |-- _c2: integer (nullable = true)
> |-- _c3: integer (nullable = true)

>#dataframe_2

>+---+
>|_c0|
>+---+
>|101|
>|201|
>|301|
>|401|
>|501|
>|601|
```

Comment: Hi @BalaKumar it would be very helpful to add meaningful names to your columns. Here you probably need an inner join i.e: df2.join(df1, df2("id") === df1("id"))

Comment: Hi @Alexandros Biratsis , thank you for your response I have tried the simple join command but my requirement is to filter all the rows i.e( filter not only values from one column in dataframe 1 but i want filter all the rows , where ever the values of dataframe 2 exist ) . The above query filters one the records based on the _c0 column values but other columns values are not taken into consideration